# Getting a text only response to a GET or POST

Tags: php, post, get

I have a VB6 application which needs to send a HTTP request to a server in order to obtain some encrypted license information (50 or so bytes).

The request can be sent using either POST or GET methods, but the response is in HTML (presumably directed at a browser) and so it is difficult to search through all the HTML to find the values I need.

What is the best way to proceed?

The server script is in PHP.

Comment: You don't have to send HTML as the response

Comment: Change the PHP to format the data how you need it.

Comment: John Conde, How to I use another response

Comment: `header("Content-Type: text/plain")`?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what language the server used, if the server response is an HTML including the license information, I'm afraid there are not many choices but fetching the response and extract the license bit.